# Change Oracle ADW default timezone

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

The ADW is configured for UTC timezone and there is need to change it to EST timezone.

The ETL custom application has many stored custom procedures which SYSDATE returns the current date and time set for the operating system.

What is the best approach to solve this problem in ADW?

Comment: Use `CURRENT_DATE` instead of `SYSDATE`. `CURRENT_DATE` uses the current session time zone instead of the time zone from operating system (which you cannot change)

Answer (score -1):

To change timezone please refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-2AF15A96-CD19-4074-8DE6-17BAD0D7DF37).

Note that this does not change the output of SYSDATE as that relies on the OS timezone which cannot be changed. The recommendation is to use CURRENT_DATE instead.

> **Upgrade Example**
>
> This example illustrates updating DST behavior to Oracle Database 11g,
> release 2 for which the default time zone version is 14. First, assume
> that your current database is using time zone version 3, and also
> assume you have an existing table t, which contains timestamp with
> time zone data.
>
> Connect to the database as the user `scott` and execute the following
> statements:

```sql
DROP TABLE t;
CREATE TABLE t (c NUMBER, mark VARCHAR(25), ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);
 
INSERT INTO t VALUES(1, 'not_affected', 
                    to_timestamp_tz('22-sep-2006 13:00:00 america/los_angeles',
                                    'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss tzr tzd'));
INSERT INTO t VALUES(4, 'affected_err_exist',
                     to_timestamp_tz('11-mar-2007 00:30:00 america/st_johns',
                                     'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss tzr tzd'));
INSERT INTO t VALUES(6, 'affected_no_err',
                     to_timestamp_tz('11-mar-2007 01:30:00 america/st_johns',
                                     'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss tzr tzd'));
INSERT INTO t VALUES(14, 'affected_err_dup', 
                     to_timestamp_tz('21-sep-2006 23:30:00 egypt',
                                     'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss tzr tzd'));
COMMIT;
```

> Then, optionally, you can start a prepare window to check the affected
> data and potential semantic errors where there is an overlap or
> non-existing time. To do this, you should start a window for
> preparation to migrate to time zone version 14. It is assumed that you
> have the necessary privileges. These privileges are controlled with
> the DBMS_DST package.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. It is unclear how the link answers the question and, if it does, it would be better to quote the appropriate sections from the documentation and provide additional explanatory commentary to make it clear. (Did you mean to link to section 4.9, rather than 4.7.2? ... even if you did, you should still quote the appropriate details so the answer is not hidden behind a link.)